# jQuery click button only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm almost completely clueless when it comes to Javascript... However I'm simply trying to tweak a userscript i use that implements jQuery to get a element by its ID and automaticlly click it... Problem is it keeps clicking it and goes into a loop. I've researched methods to prevent this such as .bind/.unbind and .one but i am unsure of how to implement them? Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 document.getElementById('submitGiftCardContinueBtn').click();
});
```

Comment: what code is being executed in the click event?

Comment: @AbeMiessler There is no code in the event, it is as it is... Perhaps the problem? Like i said it successfully clicks the button after the page loads, but it goes into a loop of clicking, i need it to just click it and either wait or just do it once.

Comment: If that is your code, it looks fine.  There is a chance that when you submit your form, it refreshes the page, which causes the .ready state to trigger again.  That will give you the infinite loop you are experiencing.

Comment: So... What happens when the button is clicked? Does the page reload? Is a form submitted? Is an event handler fired?

Comment: Are you submitting to the same form ?

Comment: Why do you want the button to be clicked when the page loads?

Comment: Yes, a form is submitted. The fields on the form are pre populated by a PHP script ive created... I'm simply trying to post them automaticlly.

Comment: I'm open to any methods or solutions, i dont need to use the code i provided, just something that works. What im looking for is similar to automatically hitting login when credentials are saved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wasn't able to reproduce this.
However, disabling the button right after clicking should be a good practice regardless,
Since (due to network latency, code efficiency, etc) there could be a lag between the click event and the actual action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('submitGiftCardContinueBtn');
    btn.click();
    btn.disabled = true;
});
```

However, it could be a better practice to call the 'on click' method when the document loads, rather than emulate a click on a UI element.

Comment: I'm not sure why but that code doesnt work, i mean it looks like it would, but it doesnt click the button. I tested it with the btn.disabled line and without, which is weird because without it its pretty much the same code just using it as a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, that didnt do the trick. I think its the scripting on the page im trying this on. I think its being reset from some AJAX refresh that validates or gives an error for the code. I've selected your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using jQuery, I'd recommend writing it as

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitGiftCardContinueBtn").click().attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

since `document.getElementById()` isn't very jQuery-ish :)

Comment: IS there a way without disabling it, we have similar situation but the button should not be disabled rather only once during the first loading of the page @Jakub Arnold